# Rss на go как получить список новостей от источника

Tags: golang, rss

В целях обучения хочу написать rss клиент на go.
Нужно сделать так:
Есть список источников(например лента новостей какого-то издания или нескольких изданий), нужно проверять появилась ли новая запись и если появилась то выводить эту запись при обращении к серверу в браузере на странице сервера(`host:port/route` rss сервера на go). То есть если зайти на ip сервера на go то можно увидеть последние новости из разных источников.(типа новостей вверху над поисковиком яндекс). Я разберусть думаю как сделать запрос в коде, сохранить содержимое и т.д. Только никак не могу понять где взять url новостных лент для проверки и как их с новостного портала перенаправить на мой сервер и показать клиенту. Буду признателен если подтолкнете в нужном направлении.

Comment: rss ленты ищите на сайтах почти любого новостного ресурса в html коде. Перенаправлять ничего не нужно - Ваш клиент просто делает http запрос и получает xml, который парсит. А показать клиенту - ну как и любую другую страницу.

Comment: если вдруг не можете найти - вот прям от stackoverflow - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds

Comment: @KoVadim Все нашел, но возникли дополнительные вопросы. Если интересно можете поучаствовать))https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325144/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-cdata-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-xml