# Вытащить CDATA если их много в xml

Tags: xml, golang

Есть xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <language>ru</language>
    <title>Lenta.ru</title>
    <description>Новости, статьи, фотографии, видео. Семь дней в неделю, 24 часа в сутки.</description>
    <link>https://lenta.ru</link>
    <image>
      <url>https://lenta.ru/images/small_logo.png</url>
      <title>Lenta.ru</title>
      <link>https://lenta.ru</link>
      <width>134</width>
      <height>22</height>
    </image>
    <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://lenta.ru/rss/top7"/>
<item>
  <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/soprotivleniye/</guid>
  <author>Марина Совина</author>
  <title>Афганское сопротивление заявило о взятии в окружение сотен талибов в Панджшере</title>
  <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/soprotivleniye/</link>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[Представитель сил фронта национального сопротивления Афганистана Али Назари заявил, что бойцам удалось взять в окружение большую группу из сотен талибов (<i>террористическое движение «Талибан», запрещено в России</i>) в окружение на северо-востоке долины Панджшер. По его словам, у террористов заканчиваются боеприпасы.]]>
  </description>
  <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:24:00 +0300</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903212507298/pic_2c640e0d167f3f8cbb39df2a5d2b5094.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="65099"/>
  <category>Мир</category>
</item>
 
<item>
  <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/wh_taliban/</guid>
  <author>Марина Совина</author>
  <title>В США рассказали о принципах дальнейшего сотрудничества с «Талибаном»</title>
  <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/wh_taliban/</link>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[Американское руководство будет исходить из конкретных действий, а не слов захватившего Афганистан Талибана (<i>террористическая организация, запрещена в России</i>) при принятии решений о дальнейшем сотрудничестве с боевиками. Среди ключевых моментов названы борьба с терроризмом и соблюдение прав человека. ]]>
  </description>
  <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:44:48 +0300</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903214213660/pic_a43b8eede2a23d7eb7ef0c145d93b8c5.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="60102"/>
  <category>Мир</category>
</item>
<item>
  <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/saleh/</guid>
  <author>Марина Совина</author>
  <title>Власти Афганистана обвинили Пакистан в поддержке вторгшихся в Панджшер талибов</title>
  <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/saleh/</link>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[Вице-президент Афганистана Амрулла Салех обвинил Пакистан в поддержке боевиков террористического движения «Талибан» (запрещено в России), которые вторглись в афганскую провинцию Панджшер. Салех сообщил, что находится на базе в Панджшерском ущелье. Он провел несколько встреч с афганскими военными командующими. ]]>
  </description>
  <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:40:00 +0300</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903214044266/pic_5124450650b5b6c7efe3a6daae70001f.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="39580"/>
  <category>Мир</category>
</item>
<item>
  <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/biden/</guid>
  <author>Марина Совина</author>
  <title>В США рассекретят материалы о терактах 11 сентября 2001 года</title>
  <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/biden/</link>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[В США рассекретят отдельные материалы, которые имеют отношение к терактам, произошедшим 11 сентября 2001 года. Соответствующий указ подписал президент США Джо Байден. Снять гриф секретности с этих материалов было одним из предвыборных обещаний американского лидера.]]>
  </description>
  <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:30:00 +0300</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903213015172/pic_d6ba1ffc85cbe6810a67cf80ab55e9b4.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="34791"/>
  <category>Мир</category>
</item>
<item>
  <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/vostochny/</guid>
  <author>Марина Совина</author>
  <title>Путин посетил космодром Восточный</title>
  <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/vostochny/</link>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[Президент России Владимир Путин посетил космодром «Восточный» и ознакомился с ходом строительства инфраструктурных объектов. В частности, глава государства осмотрел строительную площадку стартового комплекса «Ангара» и командный пункт космодрома. Путин прибыл в Амурскую область вечером в пятницу, 3 сентября.]]>
  </description>
  <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:23:00 +0300</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903212243287/pic_81b70f0813eaadbbad20fb7b0f66205c.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="118017"/>
  <category>Россия</category>
</item>
<item>
  <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/zaderzhan/</guid>
  <author>Марина Совина</author>
  <title>В Туле задержали вербовавших людей для боев в Сирии радикальных исламистов</title>
  <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/zaderzhan/</link>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[В️ Туле задержали сторонников радикального ислама, которые вербовали людей для участия в боевых действиях в Сирии. Операцию по задержанию проводили сотрудники регионального управления ФСБ России, МВД и Росгвардии. Задержанные вербовали людей для участия в боевых действиях на стороне бандформирований в Сирии. ]]>
  </description>
  <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:22:00 +0300</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903212212013/pic_d5951bb533624c58921294f81670da38.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="99564"/>
  <category>Силовые структуры</category>
</item>
<item>
  <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/polet_valkiriy/</guid>
  <author>Георгий Нестеров</author>
  <title>Украинские блогеры сплясали на военной технике под песню про «вагнеровцев»</title>
  <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/polet_valkiriy/</link>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[В Харькове блогеры пробрались на территорию «Харьковского тракторного завода». Там им удалось отыскать самоходную артиллерийскую установку 2С1 «Гвоздика». Они решили ее осмотреть, а один из них станцевал на ней под песню Акима Апачева «Лето и арбалеты», посвященную бойцам ЧВК Вагнера. ]]>
  </description>
  <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:21:00 +0300</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/20/20210903205356655/pic_9f0cf3f9d9e0e5127fdc7f5bb3012eec.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="29903"/>
  <category>Бывший СССР</category>
</item>
<item>
  <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/europe/</guid>
  <author>Марина Совина</author>
  <title>Вирусологи объяснили рост заболеваемости  COVID-19 в Европе на фоне вакцинации</title>
  <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/europe/</link>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[Несмотря на вакцинацию более 70 процентов взрослого населения, в Европе по-прежнему регистрируют высокое число заразившихся коронавирусной инфекцией за сутки. Эксперты считают, что причина заключается в распространении более заразного индийского варианта COVID-19 «дельта плюс». ]]>
  </description>
  <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:16:00 +0300</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903211615142/pic_f31724bab013b21ba9e17aacfcf7781d.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="49858"/>
  <category>Мир</category>
</item>
<item>
  <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/sochi/</guid>
  <author>Нина Ташевская</author>
  <title>Россиян предупредили о рисках при покупке жилья в Сочи</title>
  <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/sochi/</link>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[В обозримом будущем рост цен на недвижимость в Сочи продолжится, но будет более сдержанным, чем в 2020-2021 годах. В целом для инвесторов вложения в сочинские квадратные метры в ближайшие годы будут высокорискованными, предупреждают специалисты. Инвестиции могут пойти в другие города, полагают они.]]>
  </description>
  <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:11:00 +0300</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/09/20210903094647994/pic_2f88503f4c26d98beb8f2b3fd4fd4a05.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="134088"/>
  <category>Среда обитания</category>
</item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

В этом xml меня интересуют description-ы статей а именно инфа котороая находится под тэгом CDATA
Я пытаюсь достать эту инфу так
package main

```
import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Content struct {
    Data string `xml:"channel"`
}

func main() {
    var res Content
    text := []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <channel>
        <language>ru</language>
        <title>Lenta.ru</title>
        <description>Новости, статьи, фотографии, видео. Семь дней в неделю, 24 часа в сутки.</description>
        <link>https://lenta.ru</link>
        <image>
          <url>https://lenta.ru/images/small_logo.png</url>
          <title>Lenta.ru</title>
          <link>https://lenta.ru</link>
          <width>134</width>
          <height>22</height>
        </image>
        <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://lenta.ru/rss/top7"/>
    <item>
      <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/soprotivleniye/</guid>
      <author>Марина Совина</author>
      <title>Афганское сопротивление заявило о взятии в окружение сотен талибов в Панджшере</title>
      <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/soprotivleniye/</link>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[Представитель сил фронта национального сопротивления Афганистана Али Назари заявил, что бойцам удалось взять в окружение большую группу из сотен талибов (<i>террористическое движение «Талибан», запрещено в России</i>) в окружение на северо-востоке долины Панджшер. По его словам, у террористов заканчиваются боеприпасы.]]>
      </description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:24:00 +0300</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903212507298/pic_2c640e0d167f3f8cbb39df2a5d2b5094.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="65099"/>
      <category>Мир</category>
    </item>
     
    <item>
      <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/wh_taliban/</guid>
      <author>Марина Совина</author>
      <title>В США рассказали о принципах дальнейшего сотрудничества с «Талибаном»</title>
      <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/wh_taliban/</link>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[Американское руководство будет исходить из конкретных действий, а не слов захватившего Афганистан Талибана (<i>террористическая организация, запрещена в России</i>) при принятии решений о дальнейшем сотрудничестве с боевиками. Среди ключевых моментов названы борьба с терроризмом и соблюдение прав человека. ]]>
      </description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:44:48 +0300</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903214213660/pic_a43b8eede2a23d7eb7ef0c145d93b8c5.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="60102"/>
      <category>Мир</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/saleh/</guid>
      <author>Марина Совина</author>
      <title>Власти Афганистана обвинили Пакистан в поддержке вторгшихся в Панджшер талибов</title>
      <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/saleh/</link>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[Вице-президент Афганистана Амрулла Салех обвинил Пакистан в поддержке боевиков террористического движения «Талибан» (запрещено в России), которые вторглись в афганскую провинцию Панджшер. Салех сообщил, что находится на базе в Панджшерском ущелье. Он провел несколько встреч с афганскими военными командующими. ]]>
      </description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:40:00 +0300</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903214044266/pic_5124450650b5b6c7efe3a6daae70001f.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="39580"/>
      <category>Мир</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/biden/</guid>
      <author>Марина Совина</author>
      <title>В США рассекретят материалы о терактах 11 сентября 2001 года</title>
      <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/biden/</link>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[В США рассекретят отдельные материалы, которые имеют отношение к терактам, произошедшим 11 сентября 2001 года. Соответствующий указ подписал президент США Джо Байден. Снять гриф секретности с этих материалов было одним из предвыборных обещаний американского лидера.]]>
      </description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:30:00 +0300</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903213015172/pic_d6ba1ffc85cbe6810a67cf80ab55e9b4.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="34791"/>
      <category>Мир</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/vostochny/</guid>
      <author>Марина Совина</author>
      <title>Путин посетил космодром Восточный</title>
      <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/vostochny/</link>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[Президент России Владимир Путин посетил космодром «Восточный» и ознакомился с ходом строительства инфраструктурных объектов. В частности, глава государства осмотрел строительную площадку стартового комплекса «Ангара» и командный пункт космодрома. Путин прибыл в Амурскую область вечером в пятницу, 3 сентября.]]>
      </description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:23:00 +0300</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903212243287/pic_81b70f0813eaadbbad20fb7b0f66205c.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="118017"/>
      <category>Россия</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/zaderzhan/</guid>
      <author>Марина Совина</author>
      <title>В Туле задержали вербовавших людей для боев в Сирии радикальных исламистов</title>
      <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/zaderzhan/</link>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[В️ Туле задержали сторонников радикального ислама, которые вербовали людей для участия в боевых действиях в Сирии. Операцию по задержанию проводили сотрудники регионального управления ФСБ России, МВД и Росгвардии. Задержанные вербовали людей для участия в боевых действиях на стороне бандформирований в Сирии. ]]>
      </description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:22:00 +0300</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903212212013/pic_d5951bb533624c58921294f81670da38.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="99564"/>
      <category>Силовые структуры</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/polet_valkiriy/</guid>
      <author>Георгий Нестеров</author>
      <title>Украинские блогеры сплясали на военной технике под песню про «вагнеровцев»</title>
      <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/polet_valkiriy/</link>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[В Харькове блогеры пробрались на территорию «Харьковского тракторного завода». Там им удалось отыскать самоходную артиллерийскую установку 2С1 «Гвоздика». Они решили ее осмотреть, а один из них станцевал на ней под песню Акима Апачева «Лето и арбалеты», посвященную бойцам ЧВК Вагнера. ]]>
      </description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:21:00 +0300</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/20/20210903205356655/pic_9f0cf3f9d9e0e5127fdc7f5bb3012eec.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="29903"/>
      <category>Бывший СССР</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/europe/</guid>
      <author>Марина Совина</author>
      <title>Вирусологи объяснили рост заболеваемости  COVID-19 в Европе на фоне вакцинации</title>
      <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/europe/</link>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[Несмотря на вакцинацию более 70 процентов взрослого населения, в Европе по-прежнему регистрируют высокое число заразившихся коронавирусной инфекцией за сутки. Эксперты считают, что причина заключается в распространении более заразного индийского варианта COVID-19 «дельта плюс». ]]>
      </description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:16:00 +0300</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/21/20210903211615142/pic_f31724bab013b21ba9e17aacfcf7781d.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="49858"/>
      <category>Мир</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <guid>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/sochi/</guid>
      <author>Нина Ташевская</author>
      <title>Россиян предупредили о рисках при покупке жилья в Сочи</title>
      <link>https://lenta.ru/news/2021/09/03/sochi/</link>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[В обозримом будущем рост цен на недвижимость в Сочи продолжится, но будет более сдержанным, чем в 2020-2021 годах. В целом для инвесторов вложения в сочинские квадратные метры в ближайшие годы будут высокорискованными, предупреждают специалисты. Инвестиции могут пойти в другие города, полагают они.]]>
      </description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 03 Sep 2021 21:11:00 +0300</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2021/09/03/09/20210903094647994/pic_2f88503f4c26d98beb8f2b3fd4fd4a05.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="134088"/>
      <category>Среда обитания</category>
    </item>
      </channel>
    `)

    xml.Unmarshal(text, &res)

    fmt.Println(res.Data)
}
```

Сорри за много теста в коде go но я только что приступил к изучению этой темы и еще не посмотрел как сделать более цивильно.
Вопрос: Как достать из xml информацию из всех CDATA?

UPD: Получился вот такой код

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type ItemStruct struct {
    Guid        string `xml:"guid"`
    Author      string `xml:"author"`
    Title       string `xml:"title"`
    Link        string `xml:"link"`
    Description string `xml:"description"`
}

type Content struct {
    XMLName xml.Name     `xml:"description"`
    Item    []ItemStruct `xml:"item"`
}

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://lenta.ru/rss/news", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    var res Content
    for scanner.Scan() {
        text := []byte(scanner.Text()) //в text попадает содердимое .xml файла Проверил.
        xml.Unmarshal(text, &res)
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", res.Item)
    }
}
```

Но статьи все равно не выводятся. Может ли ктото подсказать как их вывести?

UPD2:
Сделал чтобы считывался весь .xml, но все равно не выводится. Пустота

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type ItemStruct struct {
    Guid        string `xml:"guid"`
    Author      string `xml:"author"`
    Title       string `xml:"title"`
    Link        string `xml:"link"`
    Description string `xml:"description"`
}

type Content struct {
    XMLName xml.Name     `xml:"channel"`
    Item    []ItemStruct `xml:"rss"`
}

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://lenta.ru/rss/top7", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(resp.Body)
    text := "`"
    for scanner.Scan() {
        text += scanner.Text()
    }
    text += "`"
    forDecrypt := []byte(text)
    var articles Content
    xml.Unmarshal(forDecrypt, &articles)
    fmt.Println(articles.Item) //пусто
    fmt.Println(articles)      //пусто
    fmt.Println(text)          //выводится полностью xml
}
```

структуры переделал на такие

```
type ItemStruct struct {
    Description string `xml:"description"`
}

type Content struct {
    XMLName xml.Name     `xml:"channel"`
    Item    []ItemStruct `xml:"description"`
}
```

Comment: Берете обычный [go-rss](https://github.com/ungerik/go-rss), загружаете файл и ищете по нему нужные вам данные. В чем вопрос-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нужные структуры

```
// в эту структуру по примеру дописываете все, что нужно
type ItemStruct struct {
  Guid        string `xml:"guid"`
  Author      string `xml:"author"`
  Title       string `xml:"title"`
  Link        string `xml:"link"`
  Description string `xml:"description"`
}

type Content struct {
  XMLName xml.Name     `xml:"channel"`
  Item    []ItemStruct `xml:"item"`
}
```

используем

```
var res Content
text := []byte('тут непереводимая игра слов, которую лучше заменить чем то более вменяемым, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds')

xml.Unmarshal(text, &res)

fmt.Printf("%v", res)
```

потерялся мой старый код, набросал новый (он чуточку другой, но у меня как минимум рабочий)

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/xml"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

type ItemStruct struct {
  Guid        string `xml:"guid"`
  Author      string `xml:"author"`
  Title       string `xml:"title"`
  Link        string `xml:"link"`
  Description string `xml:"description"`
}

type Content struct {
  XMLName xml.Name     `xml:"channel"`
  Title   string       `xml:"title"`
  Item    []ItemStruct `xml:"item"`
}

type RSS struct {
  XMLName xml.Name `xml:"rss"`
  Channel Content  `xml:"channel"`
}

func main() {
  req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://xkcd.com/rss.xml", nil)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()
  text, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

  //var articles Content
  var articles RSS
  xml.Unmarshal(text, &articles)
  for _, item := range articles.Channel.Item {
    fmt.Println(item.Title)
  }
}
```

(лента у меня не работает)

Comment: правильно я понимаю что в этой строчке `text := []byte('тут непереводимая игра слов, которую лучше заменить чем то более вменяемым, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds')`, нужно сохранить файл по ссылке и сканером по нему пройтись чтобы содержимое получить? и потом уже работать с полученным содержимым файла? нельзя  же просто вставить ссылку вместо xml разметки

Comment: просто ссылку нельзя вставить. Но там ещё несколько строк и все будет работать.

Comment: несколько строк это запрос к ресурсу от сервера?

Comment: и потом работать с resp.Body?

Comment: да, где то как здесь написано https://metanit.com/go/tutorial/9.6.php

Comment: я сделал все, и как будто какой то мелочи не хватает. На этапе unmarshal все еще нормально, текст в переменную кладется правильный, но дальше все равно не выводится нужная инфа(сами статьи по `CDATA` в `description`). Дополнил вопрос кодом

Comment: Вы вычитываете текст небольшими кусками и отдаете его парсеру. А я не уверен, что там будет читаться корректный xml кусок. Читайте все сразу. For не нужен

Comment: снова отредактировал. Добавил код в котором весь xml обрабатывается а не построчно. Только не понял, почему не нужен for. Без for считывает только первую строку xml

Comment: Отбой. Покурил гугл, нашел в чем ошибка. Там проблема в структурах. Отвечу на свой вопрос, когда до конца разберусь))) Благодарю, что направили)

Comment: немного опередили)))погуглил, нашел. Только сейчас увидел что у вас код обновился)))

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема была в том что у меня в xml монго вложенных тегов, каждый блок нужно описывать отдельной структурой, чтобы Unmarshal "понимал", в каком блоке и в каком теге начинается нужный фрагмент.  Источник который использовал я требовал создать дополнительные структуры. В итоге получился код:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type General struct {
    Rss     xml.Name   `xml:"rss"`
    Channls []LevelOne `xml:"channel"`
}

type LevelOne struct {
    Channel xml.Name     `xml:"channel"`
    Itms    []ItemStruct `xml:"item"`
}

type ItemStruct struct {
    It          xml.Name `xml:"item"`
    Description string   `xml:"description"`
}

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://lenta.ru/rss/top7", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //Лучше создать своего клиента ибо дефолтный пустой. Но для теста подходит
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(resp.Body)
    var Text string
    for scanner.Scan(){
        Text += "\n"+ scanner.Text()
    }
    forDecrypt := []byte(Text)
    var Articles General
    xml.Unmarshal(forDecrypt, &Articles)
    fmt.Println(Articles)
}
```

помог [этот](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/parsing-xml-with-golang/) ресурс и [этот](https://golang-blog.blogspot.com/2020/06/xml-package-in-golang-method-unmarshal.html)

UPD1:
Добавил в конец цикл

```
for _, item := range Articles.Channls {
        fmt.Println(item.Itms)
    }
```

Существенно ничего не изменилось, буду разбираться как сделать вывод более приемлемым) Но основная цель достигнута.